# C - Struct- Integer to a pointer without cast

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

So I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out what is going on when I `malloc` an array that is a member of the `struct`?
The following `error` message occurred :

> "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast".

It would be greatly appreciated if someone can help me see where I went wrong in the `malloc`.

```
typedef struct _big_num {
   int  nbytes;  // size of array
   Byte *bytes;  /// array of Bytes
} BigNum;

void initBigNum(BigNum *n, int Nbytes)
{
    int i;
    n->nbytes = Nbytes;
    for (i = 0; i < Nbytes; i++) {
       n->bytes[i] = malloc(sizeof(Byte));   //This is where the error came up
       n->bytes[i] = 0;
       assert(n->bytes[i] == 0);
}
return;
}
```

Comment: What's `n->bytes[i]`? Are you sure this index exists (you have permission to access it)?

Answer (score 2):

`n->bytes[i]` is of type `Byte`, it's a single element in the "array". The `malloc` call returns a *pointer*.

You don't allocate the array itself, but instead try to allocate each element separately, which isn't how it works. Besides the compiler message, `n->bytes` may not point to a valid location, making the dereference `n->bytes[i]` invalid for *any* index.

You probably want

```
void initBifNum(BigNum *n, int NBytes)
{
    // Initialize members and allocate memory for array
    n->nbytes = NBytes;
    n->bytes = malloc(sizeof *n->bytes * NBytes);

    // Initialize all elements in the array to zero
    memset(n->bytes, 0, sizeof *n->nbytes * NBytes);
}
```

Comment: Sentences written in the imperative mood, as “You don’t allocate the array itself, but instead try to allocate…,” are at risk of being misinterpreted as instructions to do something. This would be clearer written as declarative for the part that describes the current code, as in “The code you show in the question attempts to allocate each element separately. Instead, you should allocate an array of `Byte` objects and set the pointer `bytes` to point to the start of them.”

Comment: Similarly, a clause such as “`n->bytes` may not point to a valid location“ can be interpreted as a prohibition on setting `n->bytes` to point to a valid location.

Comment: `calloc` is easier to read and less error-prone (and probably faster) than `malloc` followed by `memset`

Answer (score -1):

`n->bytes[i]` is really `*n->(bytes+i)`. So you're assigning the memory address returned by `malloc` to type Byte instead of to a pointer.

It's worth pointing out that in the very next line, you assign 0 to `n->bytes[i]`, even though you just attempted to assign it an address. If you're trying to allocate memory that's set to 0, just use `calloc` - it allocates memory and sets it to 0 for you.

Comment: It is `(n->bytes)[i]`. The grammar for `->` is that the second operand must be an identifier. `n->(X)` is a syntax error and makes no sense either.